# How do you set up HTTP ACL's for a WCF 3.0 REST application on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, netsh

I have been reading O'Reilly's "RESTful .NET" and am working with the example program on pg. 24 - 25.  This sets up a custom binding for handling REST requests.  When I execute the code, it fails as it does not have permission to set up listening on http://localhost:8889/TestHttp

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28VS.100%29.aspx), I need to configue **netsh**.  I am using the following netsh string:

**netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:8889/TestHttp user=DOMAIN\user**

where DOMAIN\user is customized to my account.

This appears to process in an additional console window, but executing my code causes the same failure.  Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on vista or windows 7 you need to run a cmd.exe session or powershell as administrator then run the command.

Comment: The command completes successfully, but VS 2010 reports "Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)."  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Got it!  I had to launch VS 2010 Beta 2 as an administrator.