# WCF on Windows 7 not working

Tags: wcf, windows-7, firewall

I am using an example from iDesign about one way calls. I can get it to work on a Vista machine (VS2008) but not on a windows 7 machine (VS2010).

I get this error:

`HTTP could not register URL http://+:8001/MyService/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace`

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.Open();
```

I get the error on the `host.Open();` line. I noticed that windows asks first for some firewall and to give permission which I did but still it is not working. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how the security for vista and later versions of windows deal with port access.  The Post below has the command you need to run.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027450/2028403#2028403)

Answer (score 0):

Have you reserved that namespace? The [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353) that is in the exception message tells you how, however as you appear to have missed or not gotten that

Open an elevated command prompt and run

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8001/MyService/ user=DOMAIN\user
```

replacing DOMAIN\user with your account details, or a suitable group